# How to implement type hinting for DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, type-hinting, python-typing, python-polars

I would like to have same sort of Python type hinting on Polars DataFrame. Since DataFrame is not a generic type, I cannot do DataFrame[MyFrameSchema].

For example:

```
MyFrameSchema = {'price': float, 'quantity': int, 'product_name': str}
```

or:

```
class MyDataFrame(pl.DataFrame)
    ...
```

I now Polars has type SchemaDict in DataFrame constructor `from polars.type_aliases import SchemaDict`, but I don't know how to use it in Python code.

Maybe someone has idea how to wrap DataFrame into TMyDataFrame
Something like `TMyDataFrame: TypeAlias = ...` or something else. I am open for suggestions.

Comment: If it is not generic you need to either write your own generic wrapper class around it or your own type stubs for it. I see no other way.